# Group Theory : A property related to the intersection of all subgroups

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was solving a problem from the book by Herstein (problem 2.5.2) and came across the following solution (the question is given there itself): http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1083399p4773230

Can someone give me an example of such a situation?
[Edit] In other words a group with the property that the intersection of its non-trivial subgroups is non-trivial as well. [/Edit]

Comment: Please make your questions as self-contained as possible in the future. Judging from the answer I guessed what exactly you are asking, and edited it in. Roll it back if you disagree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinite group with this property is the following subgroup of the multiplicative group of complex numbers
$$
G=\{z\in\Bbb{C}\mid z^{2^n}=1\ \text{for some natural number $n$}\}.
$$
If $z\in G$ is $\neq1$, then $-1$ will also be a power of $z$. This is because if $k$ is the smallest non-negative integer with the property $z^{2^k}=1$ then we have $k>0$ (otherwise $z=1$). Consequently $W:=z^{2^{k-1}}$ satisfies both $w^2=1$ and $w\neq1$, so $w=-1$.

Therefore $-1$ belongs to the intersection of all non-trivial subgroups of $G$. Clearly $G$ is an infinite group, so this example works.

---

We can use any prime number $p$ in place of $2$ above. In the more general case all the roots of unity of order $p$ will be contained in the intersection of all the non-trivial subgroups.

Comment: Thank you sir! Also being new to forums, I will take care next time.

Comment: No problem, @AlmondPie. In your shoes I might have kept David Wheeler's answer as the accepted one. After all, the group I describe IS the Prüfer $2$-group he mentions in a comment. His comment must have come while I was typing/polishing my answer. Otherwise I would have refrained from answering.

Comment: Lol, Jyrki, it's all good. Almond Pie got the information he was after which is the important thing.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, consider the cyclic group of order $4$. It has precisely $2$ non-trivial subgroups, the entire group, and the unique subgroup of order $2$. The intersection of these groups is the subgroup of order $2$.

You can generalize this to any cyclic group of order $p^n$, for $p$ a prime.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a group whose order is infinite and holds this property?

Comment: The Prüfer $p$-group ought to do it.